# How to match id with current id in array

Tags: flutter

> How I will check current user id == id and show user like or not in UI

```
"reference":[
{
"id":"123",
"userid"234"
},
{
"id":"1423",
"userid"25534"
},
{
"id":"15423",
"userid"2335534"
},

]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is json response try to convert it in models using https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

or here is code that can work for u

```
  var reference = [
    {"id": "123", "userid": "234"},
    {"id": "1423", "userid": "25534"},
    {"id": "15423", "userid": "2335534"},
 ];

 var r = reference.firstWhere((e) => e["id"] == "123");

 print(r);

 // output

 {id: 123, userid: 234}
```